# Django Retrieve last 10 records for a given query

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I was reading the django documentation, and thought this would work to limit to resulting query results to the last 10 results, but it isnt doing that.

Here my db query:

```
TSUH = TSUH.objects.filter(FKToUser_id=request.user).all()[10:]
    TSFH = TSFH.objects.filter(FKToUser_id=request.user).all()[10:]
    TSJH = TSJH.objects.filter(FKToUser_id=request.user).all()[10:]

    return render(request, page.html', {
         'GivenTSUH':TSUH

    })
```

my  template contains:

```
    {% if TSUH %}
        {% for T in TSUH %}
            <li>{{ T.scanBegin }}<span> to <span>{{ T.begin }}</span> </li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        It appears there are no results.
    {% endif %}
```

This is returning a lot more than 10 results for each query. is the `all()` throwing it off?

Thoughts? Thanks

Comment: How you determine last records by datetime or pk?

Comment: i could do either, which is more db efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect syntax. It should be number after `:` not before. Also you can use [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#reverse) to change query ordering, like this:

```
TSUH = TSUH.objects.filter(FKToUser_id=request.user).reverse()[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
TSFH = TSFH.objects.filter(FKToUser_id=request.user).all().order_by('-pk').[:10]
TSJH = TSJH.objects.filter(FKToUser_id=request.user).all().order_by('-pk').[:10]
```

This will give 10 last inserted records.